# "It's not true what they said. They're lying." Why are we using Present Continuous here? They have already lied, so why?

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense

I don't understand why we use Present Continous there, because the action has already ended, "they have already lied".

Comment: I think there's an implication that their dishonesty is permanent. You'd say "They were lying" otherwise, eg if they later told the truth.

Comment: Perhaps because it concerns an ongoing situation.

Comment: While you could say they lied, that addresses the past. Here, we may be stuck with their lie today. Not *That wasn't true*, but *That isn't true. It's a lie. They're lying*.

Comment: If _they_ are still speaking, and if _they_ have not yet acknowledged _their_ past lie, then _they_'re still lying.

Comment: Perhaps they were taped.

Answer (score 1):

"They're lying" is the most common way of expressing this concept in English.  It's often a visceral statement.  Unless there's more to the story that the person is about to explain, and some kind of past tense is needed so that the rest of the story will be clear, people are likely to deliver "They're lying" as the final, dramatic punch line, as in the example you included in your title.

I don't know how to document this -- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The continuous form of verbs always implies that the action is not complete **at the time referred to**.

With this in mind, the present continuous is appropriate as the speaker wishes to use this rhetorical device to imply that not only did the other person lie, but that they will continue to lie, i.e. their lying is not yet complete.

Were the speaker to have said "They **have been** lying!" It would allow for the possibility that, if challenged, the other person might start to tell the truth.

Answer (score 0):

While it's clear that grammatically, 'They're lying' should have been 'They lied' or 'They were lying' or some other past tense, grammar is not the point.

'It's not true what they said…' sounds to me more like a fabrication for the sake of argument than anyone's real statement, still 'They're lying' would be the idiomatic response, because that's the way most of think, and speak.

In most cases - and I suggest this is one - idiom over-rides all the formal rules.